# Python splitting multiple lists

Tags: python

How can I split a list with multiple lists within in and store them in some sort of variable so they can be tested.

For example

```
[[2,3], [6,1,7,2], [3,4,1]]
```

Upon splitting will be something like this

```
[2,3]
[6,1,7,2]
[3,5,1,]
```

Where I can use each one of them as parameters for my other functions. 
Is this possible, if so how can I produce this?

Thanks in advance, new to python sorry!

Comment: I'll say they are already splitted

Comment: But why do you want to split and then pass to a function? if your `lst = [[2,3], [6,1,7,2], [3,4,1]]` and your method requires the first and last element, then simply do: `call_method(lst[0], lst[2])`

Comment: Do you have sub-lists with sub-lists? e.g. [[4, [5, 6]], [7, 8]]. Do you have individual items? e.g. [4, [5,6], [7, 8]].

Comment: You can use list comprehension to test each list separately. 
for example `[func(x) for x in arr]`

Comment: are you looking for a `for` loop? `for x in list: ...` stores each element in x, in turn.

Comment: Oh, ZdaR if I was to type say 1st[0], it would return [2,3]?

Comment: @Bruce219 I don't think `1st` is a good name for a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in [[2,3], [6,1,7,2], [3,4,1]]:
    your_f(*x)
```

This will loop through the list of lists, selecting each sublist as x, and then unpacking the contents as parameters in `your_f` via the `*` (which has a special name somewhere).

Aka on the first iteration, the code will execute `your_f(2, 3)`

Comment: When `*` is used for unpacking it's often called the splat operator.

Comment: Anytime Brucey! @Bruce219

Comment: @Bruce219 If you need the whole sublist as a parameter then just drop the splat

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract inner lists to other variables you can use this:

```
li = [[2,3], [6,1,7,2], [3,4,1]]
a, b, c = li
print(a, b, c)
```

output is `[2, 3] [6, 1, 7, 2] [3, 4, 1]`

If you have a function that takes three lists you can use this:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

foo(*li)
```

output is the same.
It is called [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: This was sort of the thing I was looking for, however, the "for statement" was better used instead of initializing a,b,c because my list is not predefined.